# How to ensure my async function executes first before calling next function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

My program is supposed to parse the results of a SQL query into a CSV file, then save to an FTP and S3 bucket. `connectSQL` is an async function that needs to execute completely before calling the `writeToCSV` function, but so far no matter what I've tried, `writeToCSV` executes before `connectSQL`, giving me an empty CSV file. How can I ensure that `connectSQL` executes before anything else?

```js
function dataRefresh(){
 var resu = connectSQL();
 writeToCSV(resu);
}

async function connectSQL(){
 try {
  const sqlConfig = {
           // db connection config
  };
  
  const sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
  
    let pool = await sql.connect(sqlConfig);
    let result = await pool.request().query(sqlQuery);
    return result;
 } catch(err){
  throw err;
 }
}

function writeToCSV(event){
 // Parse to CSV
 var csv = parser({data: event.Records, fields: fields});
 // Write CSV to local directory
 fs.writeFile(fileName, csv, function(err){
  if (err){
   throw err;
  } else{
   console.log("Data saved locally");
  }
 });
}
```

I've tried reading as much as I can about asynchronous calls, and I feel I have a good understanding of what they're used for, but I've come up empty trying to solve my specific issue.

Comment: The code you show shouldn't even work. `connectSQL` returns a Promise, and a Promise doesn't have a `Records` property. You're just missing an `await` somewhere (which would fix your original problem too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) resolving to the return value of the function. You can either treat it like a promise and use `.then()`, or turn `dataRefresh` async as well and use `await`:

```
function dataRefresh(){
    connectSQL().then(result => writeToCSV(result));
    // or simply:
    // connectSQL().then(writeToCSV);
}
```

or

```
async function dataRefresh(){
    var result = await connectSQL();
    writeToCSV(result);
}
```

Comment: you can refactor the first function into just `connectSQL().then(writeToCSV)`

Comment: @Touffy Good addition! I decided to leave the arrow function visible because it may be more clear for a less-experienced Javascript programmer to see the parameter being passed in.

Comment: Fair enough. The same would apply to rewriting the second function as `writeToCSV(await connectSQL())` of course ;)

Comment: Thanks so much! I used @Touffy 's suggestion, and it worked. I'll look more into promises

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your code is running in an environment where async functions work, then I think all you need to do is add `await` in front of the call to `connectSQL` inside `dataRefresh` like so:

```
async function dataRefresh(){
    var resu = await connectSQL();
    writeToCSV(resu);
}
```

Comment: …and of course you would need to make that function `async`.

Comment: Recall that the `await` operator [can only be used inside `async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) :)